# How to get multiple values of last entered row in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a question regarding identity or last entered values. I have a datatable in which there are 3 primary key i mean they are composite primary key which are 'tendercode', 'LocationID' and 'Layer' in which tendercode may have same number or at least one of them will be different like this as follow

```
TenderCode            LocationID            Layer
1                      MIN-001                L1
1                      MIN-001                L2
1                      AHM-001                L1
2                      MIN-001                L1
3                      AHM-001                L3
```

Like this are my table but the problem is I need to know which is the last entered record in trigger and "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)" return only single value as per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: primary key and identity key is diferent.

Comment: SQL Server triggers are statement not row based. Please explain what is your actual goal? What are you planning to do with primary key values?

Comment: I'm looking for any event or function by which i can get the last row inserted in the datatable.

Comment: At what point are you requesting this information?  From inside the trigger (then @Dd2's answer may work for you)?  From some other point?  Depending on a number of things this might be difficult - do you have an `inserted_at` timestamp or an auto-increment id?  Also, what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a trigger, then [inserted table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Also, [OUTPUT clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) could help you.

Source [here](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/).